# Энергосбережение Android приложений

Tags: java, android, whitelist

Как приложения Viber, Whatsapp и подобные при установке автоматически добавляются в список исключений энергопотребления для приложений, написанных на Java?

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46142287) вы точно найдёте ответ

Comment: Нету там того, что нужно.